# 'ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead' on sklearn

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I don't know why I get this error message. I've transformed the inputs into a matrix. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Patrick Omens\Downloads\real_estate_price_size.csv')

x = data['size']
y = data['price']

x_matrix = x.values.reshape(-1,1)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(x_matrix,y)

reg.predict(750)
```

I get the error after this, and I would like to know why. Thank you!

Comment: Your x data should be an array of n rows by 1 column. reshape(n, 1)

Comment: x.tonumpy.reshape(n, 1); n being the number of rows.

Comment: Actually, reshape(-1, 1) should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass a 2D array to `predict` method. Use:

```
prediction = reg.predict([[750]])
```